# How do I update the last_updated column default set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Tags: yii2, crud

I am using Gii generated CRUD . There is a column `last_updated` which default set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in phpmyadmin.

when I create the row row it takes current Date and time .

But when I Update the row it takes the previous date and time (date n time when row creted).

I want , when I update the row it should take current Date n Time?
how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this behaviour into your model.Or create a common model Which extends to all your models and add it there. so that you need not rewrite in all the models.

```
    public function behaviors() {

    return[
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'updated_at',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like:

```
$model->updated_at = time();
```

or

```
$model->touch('updated_at');
```

to make the field get the current timestamp!

Comment: Please make sure you have got `TimestampBehavior` attached otherwise method `touch` is not available.

Answer (score 0):

In your ActiveRecord, extend function `beforeSave()` like this:

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {
    //...
    $this->last_updated = time();
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Or, as Saberi pointed out, `TimestampBehavior` can be used to fill in current timestamp to your active record's attributes. Use this code to do it as part of the saving process (similar to calling beforeSave()):

```
use yii\db\Expression;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'last_updated',
            'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Or, use `$model->touch('last_updated');` to simply update the timestamp of an existing record

See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html)